# bash script using awk to rename file using timestamp

Tags: bash, awk

I started working on a script to rename files based on timestamp.  I thought I had it worked out on the command line but not working as a script.  Script hangs in the awk line.

This is the little script so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
#renamePhotos.sh
#  a script to rename photos in current directory based on date
#  to be expanded

#  OUTPUT in $(ls -tr *.JPG); 
LIST="$(ls --full-time -tr *.JPG)"
echo "Starting..."

for i in "$LIST"; do
    echo  $(awk '{ print $6 }' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "-" }; { print $1 }')
    echo
done
```

Comment: AWK is not hanging, it is waiting for input. I do not see `i` being used the `awk` line! Instead of `awk` you can use `cut -f 6` to get the 6th field.

Comment: can you please post sample input and output data ?

Comment: Please [don't parse the output of `ls`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/86440) — if you want to do this in a shell script, use [`stat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html) with a format string to directly get the information you want in the appropriate format.

Comment: thanks for the help I managed to get a result using this line                                                                              echo "$i" | awk '{ print $6 }' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "-" }; { print $1 $2 $3 }'
 but now I realized my loop is not getting me what I want as @ilkkachu alludes to below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
echo  $(awk '{ print $6 }' | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "-" }; { print $1 }')
```

The first awk inside the command substitution doesn't have any input specified, so it reads from stdin, which is connected to your terminal, meaning that it waits for you to give it some input.

To give it some input from shell variable, you'd likely want to pipe it in:

```
echo "$var" | awk...
```

Doing `echo $(foo bar)` looks odd, since echo will just print the output of the command `foo bar` which would happen in any case if you just ran `foo bar` by itself. (Apart from word-splitting, but it's likely that wasn't what you were looking for.)

Also, the for loop.

```
for i in "$LIST"; do
```

will only run once, with `i` set to the value of `LIST`. Since `$LIST` is quoted, it doesn't go through word-splitting, and `for` only sees one item in the list. Though if you do it without quotes, as in `for i in $LIST; do...`, you'll see that it splits on spaces too. You'd need to set `IFS` to a newline to stop that.

Even after that there's the possible problem that the output of `ls` can be a bit tricky: the time format might change according to the locale (though I'm not sure if that happens with `--full-time`), and it can mangle unprintable characters in file names. If you know your locale and that the file names are "nice", it might work.

An alternative would be to let the shell find the files, and use something like `date --reference $file` (if you have that), to get the date:

```
for f in *.jpg ; do 
    d=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" -r "$f")  
    echo "$d $f" 
done
```

(GNU coreutils `date` has the `--reference` flag. `date -r` on OS X takes a time instead of a file.)